# Getting a Javascript value with ASP.NET Webforms

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, webforms

I'm trying to get the width of text in PX, which I'm doing successfully in Javascript. I now want to pass this value into C#.

```
<p id="Test">This is where I measure the text in PX</p>    
</br>

<!-- JS showing the value -->
<input type="hidden" id="widthOutput" runat="server" />
</br> 

<!-- Button to execute the C# -->
<asp:Button ID="calc" OnClick="calc_Click" runat="server" Text="Button" />
</br>   

<!-- C# showing the value -->
<asp:Literal ID="output" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
```

And the Javascript, which does return the correct values, but only in the console

```
var fontSize = 12;
var test = document.getElementById("Test");
test.style.fontSize = fontSize;
var height = (test.clientHeight + 1) + "px";
var width = (test.clientWidth + 1) + "px"
document.getElementById("widthOutput").Value = width;
console.log(height, width);
```

And my C#

```
protected void calc_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
output.Text = widthOutput.Value;
}
```

- I have looked on Stack Overflow for the answer, which made me change my JS a little, but still no luck. Still relatively new to C# and terrible at JS so apologies if it's simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your JS Code you are using `.Value` instead of `.value` (case sensitive)

Comment: Wow, that's embarrassing. It's working now. Thanks!